# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://site.ru/page/param"

Tags: css, .htaccess, apache

Здравствуйте в чем может быть проблема, когда задаю параметр http://site.ru/page/param в param или ставлю слэш дополнительный на сайте слетают стили и скрипты, в консоли выводит ошибку:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://site.ru/page/param".

И указывает на строку подключения стилей:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">`

Сервер apache, в .htaccess стоит Options -Multiviews

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `href="../css/style.css"` на `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: Спасибо,все работает, а из-за чего происходит такое? Ведь если я скопирую ссылку у меня откроется файлик с ксс в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

Вы указываете ссылку относительно текущей директории, нужно указать относительно корневой директории, замените

```
href="../css/style.css"
```

на

```
href="/css/style.css"
```

Comment: Спасибо,все работает, а из-за чего происходит такое? Ведь если я скопирую ссылку у меня откроется файлик с ксс в браузере