# Видит файл стилей, но не видит правила?

Tags: php, html, css

Сделал сжатие стилей и скриптов при помощи `compress.php` от **Google**. Скрипты работают на ура. А вот стили (файл) видит, видит что внутри, но не видит правила. Стоит открыть средство разработчика и поставить пробел в любом месте сжатого файла `css` и всё сразу видит и стили применяются. 
Броузеры выдают:

> warning: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http:.../min/css_all_min_1540072509.cssgz".

Вставляю файл в html так:

```
<? require_once(ROOT.'/service/compress_timestamp.php');
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'],'GZIP')!==false)
        $gz='gz';
 else
        $gz=null;
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/template/min/css_all_min_'.$compress_stamp.'.css'.$gz.'" />',PHP_EOL;
    ?>
```

В чём дело?

Comment: Ну вы и сами наверное видите префикс gz, в конце расширения стилей. Интуитивно думаю и вам понятно в чем дело...

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Если бы понятно было бы не спросил бы. Броузеры видят эту таблицу стилей. https://hkar.ru/VS4o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<? require_once(ROOT.'/service/compress_timestamp.php');
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'],'GZIP')!==false)
        $gz='gz';
 else
        $gz=null;
echo '<style>'.file_get_contents(ROOT.'/template/min/css_all_min_'.$compress_stamp.'.css').'</style>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Данная статья](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22631158/10324181) вам подробно объяснит в чем дело.

Так же, могу предположить, что вы не корректно указали путь к файлу стилей.

[А данный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592916/308317) так же может вам помочь.

Comment: Путь корректно. Он же видит таблицу. Но я ж указал rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" (хотя type="text/css" это уже и не нужно по станданрту html 5)

Comment: Не это у style не надо указывать "text/css"